# How would I go about installing an AverTV Hybrid Volar HX?

Tags: 11.10, installation, drivers, tv-tuner

How can I install the driver to get my AverTV Hybrid Volar HX working on brand new Ubuntu 11.10 computer?
I'am a newby in linux world but Ubuntu looks great. Please give me a hand!

Comment: At first install tvtime from Software Center.

Comment: done! system doesn't found a video source

Answer (score 1):

This is for 64 bit drivers, but probably the same solution applies to the 32-bit version by just using x86 instead of x64 in filenames. The solution is inspired in the great work by the guys of [linuxtv.org](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia_AverTV_Hybrid_Volar_HX_%28A827%29#Kernel_2.6.36.2C_2.6.37.2C_2.6.38.2C_2.6.39.2C_3.0.x.2C_3.1.x.2C_3.2.0)

1. Create a directory called AverTVVolarHX in your home
2. Download C038A827H826_Installer_x64_0.10-Beta_091126.zip from [AverMedia WebSite](http://www.avermedia.com/Product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=293&tab=APDriver) to that directory
3. Create in same directory patch file aver.patch:

   ```
   diff -Nr -u0 original/installer/installer.sh modified/installer/installer.sh
   --- original/installer/installer.sh     2009-11-13 11:47:33.000000000 +0100
   +++ modified/installer/installer.sh     2011-08-28 20:58:38.000000000 +0200
   @@ -177,13 +176,0 @@
   -       if [[ "$kversion" != "2" || "$kpatchlevel" != "6" ]]; then
   -               dialog --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
   -               --title "Kernel version error" \
   -               --msgbox "Installer cannot determine kernel version or the running kernel is not 2.6.x kernel. \n\
   -Installer will abort now.
   -" \
   -               10 $WIDTH
   -               log "generate_kdep_string: wrong kernel version ${kversion}.${kpatchlevel}.${ksublevel}. Abort."
   -        log_from_file $ksrc/Makefile #s016
   -        log_from_file $kobj/Makefile #s016
   -               exit
   -       fi
   -
   @@ -994,3 +980,0 @@
   -   # check if root
   -   log "check if root: EUID=$EUID"
   -   if [[ "$EUID" != "0" ]]; then
   @@ -998,9 +981,0 @@
   -       dialog --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
   -       --title "ERROR: " \
   -       --msgbox \
   -       "You must be root to run installer. \
   -\nPlease login as root or use 'su' or 'sudo' to abtain root privilege. \
   -\nInstaller will now abort." 10 $WIDTH
   -       clear
   -       exit
   -   fi
   diff -Nr -u0 original/installer/src/aver/osdep.c modified/installer/src/aver/osdep.c
   --- original/installer/src/aver/osdep.c 2009-11-13 11:54:56.000000000 +0100
   +++ modified/installer/src/aver/osdep.c 2011-08-28 20:19:19.000000000 +0200
   @@ -89 +88,0 @@
   -#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
   @@ -435 +434 @@
   -               init_MUTEX(tmp);
   +               sema_init(tmp, 1);
   @@ -439 +438 @@
   -               init_MUTEX_LOCKED(tmp);
   +               sema_init(tmp, 0);
   @@ -1069,0 +1069 @@
   +static DEFINE_MUTEX(dvbdev_mutex);
   @@ -1072 +1072 @@
   -       lock_kernel();
   +       mutex_lock(&dvbdev_mutex);
   @@ -1077 +1077 @@
   -       unlock_kernel();
   +       mutex_unlock(&dvbdev_mutex);
   diff -Nr -u0 original/installer/src/aver/osdep_dvb.c modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_dvb.c
   --- original/installer/src/aver/osdep_dvb.c     2009-11-13 11:54:57.000000000 +0100
   +++ modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_dvb.c     2011-08-28 20:19:36.000000000 +0200
   @@ -79 +78,0 @@
   -#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
   @@ -233 +232 @@
   -               init_MUTEX(&p->feedlock);
   +               sema_init(&p->feedlock, 1);
   diff -Nr -u0 original/installer/src/aver/osdep_th2.c modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_th2.c
   --- original/installer/src/aver/osdep_th2.c     2009-11-13 11:54:57.000000000 +0100
   +++ modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_th2.c     2011-08-28 20:20:00.000000000 +0200
   @@ -78 +77,0 @@
   -#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
   @@ -80,0 +80 @@
   +#include "osdep.h"
   @@ -90 +90 @@
   -        lock_kernel();
   +        SysLockKernel();
   @@ -100 +100 @@
   -        unlock_kernel();
   +        SysUnlockKernel();
   diff -Nr -u0 original/installer/src/aver/osdep_v4l2.c modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_v4l2.c
   --- original/installer/src/aver/osdep_v4l2.c    2009-11-13 11:54:58.000000000 +0100
   +++ modified/installer/src/aver/osdep_v4l2.c    2011-08-28 20:20:19.000000000 +0200
   @@ -75,0 +76,2 @@
   +#define VFL_TYPE_VTX 3
   +
   @@ -84 +85,0 @@
   -#include <linux/smp_lock.h>
   ```
4. Open terminal

   ```
   $ cd ~/AverTVVolarHX
   $ unzip C038A827H826_Installer_x64_0.10-Beta_091126.zip
   $ cd H826D_Installer_x64_0.10-Beta
   $ tail -n +115 AVERMEDIA-Linux-x64-H826D-0.10-beta.sh | bzip2 -d | tar xf -
   $ patch -l -p1 < ../aver.patch
   $ cd installer
   $ ./installer.sh
   ```
5. During the installation choose Expert Installation, select /home/<youruser>/AverTVVolarHX as the directory for expert installation and finish installation (it just will output the module sources to /home/<youruser>/AverTVVolarHX/H826D-expert-install)
6. Now you need an hex editor, e.g. ghex, which is in the default repositories. Hex edit file /home/<youruser>/AverTVVolarHX/H826D-expert-install/aver/osdep_dvb.o_shipped and replace param_array_get and param_array_set by param_array_ops
7. Create in directory /home/<youruser>/AverTVVolarHX/H826D-expert-install installer.sh:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -i

   # get absolute path of this script
   BASE=`(cd \`dirname $0\`; pwd)`

   TARGET_DIR=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-usb

   if [[ "$EUID" != "0" ]]; then
       echo -e "You must be root to run installer. 
   \nPlease login as root or use 'su' or 'sudo' to obtain root privileges.
   \nInstaller will now abort."
       exit
   fi

   cd "$BASE"

   make || { echo "make failed"; exit 1; }

   echo -e "\nCopying h826d.ko to $TARGET_DIR/h826d.ko"
   cp -r h826d.ko $TARGET_DIR/ || { echo "copy failed"; exit 1; }

   echo -e "\nCopying averusbh826d.ko to $TARGET_DIR/averusbh826d.ko"
   cp -r averusbh826d.ko $TARGET_DIR/ || { echo "copy failed"; exit 1; }

   echo -e "\nRunning depmod -a"
   depmod -a || { echo "depmod failed"; exit 1; }

   echo -e "\nCleaning"
   make clean || { echo "make clean failed"; exit 1; }

   echo -e "\nCompleted"
   ```
8. Finally run installer.sh

   ```
   $ cd /home/<youruser>/AverTVVolarHX/H826D-expert-install
   $ chmod +x installer.sh
   $ sudo ./installer.sh
   ```

The H826D-expert-install directory is the only thing you need for future recompilations, so save it somewhere else. The other files and dirs can now be safely deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Please read this](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/AVerMedia_AverTV_Hybrid_Volar_HX_%28A827%29)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.